# PHP arrange "SELECT OPTIONS" by ID

Tags: php

I was wondering how can i arrange my options in  form by php by ID?

```
<option value="9171">Name1</option>
<option value="5063">Name1</option>
<option value="6167">Name1</option>
<option value="5208">Name1</option>
<option value="4917">Name1</option>
<option value="4938">Name1</option>
<option value="6193">Name1</option>
<option value="6192">Name1</option>
<option value="5342">Name1</option>
<option value="6157">Name1</option>
<option value="5228">Name1</option>
<option value="2126">Name1</option>
<option value="1668">Name1</option>
<option value="6186">Name1</option>
<option value="5343">Name1</option>
<option value="4915">Name1</option>
<option value="9217">Name1</option>
<option value="7160">Name1</option>
<option value="9025">Name1</option>
<option value="9066">Name1</option>
<option value="9092">Name1</option>
```

From  PHP, how can I arrange that by ID order? The ID is the values of the options. I am getting the IDS from media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json

Comment: Where are you getting the ids from? manually typed or from a database?

Comment: Depends on how you are producing this HTML in the first place.

Comment: http://php.net/ksort, most likely.

Comment: @AliTrixx media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json

Comment: @user2733875 - are you using PHP to retrieve that? Could you add the code to your question, in that case?

Comment: @andrewsi I need help with that

Comment: With what, sorry? Your question says that you're retrieving the values already.

Comment: @andrewsi I need a PHP script to make the select options in order by ID

Comment: @user2733875 How has your JSON turned into HTML? Post that code!

Comment: @user2733875 - and you've said that you're getting the IDs from another website. Can you add the code that you've written to do that to the question, so we can work with it?

Comment: I put it in random order the options above so No

Comment: @user2733875 - So you generated the file above manually? And you want to re-order that file by PHP? Or did you want a script that goes and gets the data from the server and re-orders it when it's loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: If you really have to sort the `<option/>` list, you can do like that:

```
$options = <<<EOD
<option value="4917">Name1</option>
<option value="4938">Name1</option>
<option value="6193">Name1</option>
<option value="22">Name1</option>
<option value="5342">Name1</option>
<option value="6157">Name1</option>
<option value="7160">Name1</option>
<option value="9025">Name1</option>
<option value="9066">Name1</option>
<option value="1">Name1</option>
EOD;

$optionsArray = explode("\n", $options);
natsort($optionsArray);

print_r($optionsArray);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [9] => <option value="1">Name1</option>
    [3] => <option value="22">Name1</option>
    [0] => <option value="4917">Name1</option>
    ...
)
```

Note the [`natsort`](http://php.net/natsort), which makes sure the `1` and `22` values are sorted properly.

**EDIT END**.

```
// $json = file_get_contents('http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json');
$json = file_get_contents('paper_items.json');
$items = json_decode($json);

// sort by paper_item_id by keying by it
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $ordered[$item->paper_item_id] = $item;
}

// output options sorted by paper_item_id
$options = '';
foreach ($ordered as $id => $item)
{
    $options .= "<option value=\"$id\">$item->label</option>\n";
}

print $options;
```

Result:

```
<option value="1">Blue</option>
<option value="2">Green</option>
<option value="3">Pink</option>
<option value="4">Black</option>
<option value="5">Red</option>
...
```

Comment: Actually `$options = '';` should be `$options = '<select size="1" name="names_example">';` and above `print $options;` should be `$options .= "</select>";` - Your code (as is) did not produce a dropdown menu, unless that's what the OP wants.

Comment: The question was "how can i arrange my options by ID?", not "how can i produce a dropdown menu".

Comment: I know how to do that, but I need MY ITEMS ABOVE  to be in ID order

Comment: @ax. I'm aware of that. But why even include `<option value=\"$id\">$item->label</option>` if it's not going to produce one in the first place?

Comment: @user2733875 So you cannot order the items _before_ generating the <option/> list? You get them from the json, don't you?

Comment: The items above are not in ID order it was in ABC order

Comment: @user2733875 I know. My question is if, in your code, you have the chance to access and modify the raw data (the json) before generating the <option/>s. Do you?

Comment: @ax. I do not have it

Comment: @ax. Can you make a script that arranges my items.txt (the select options) by ID order?

Comment: @user2733875 See my edit to my answer.

Comment: @ax. Works, can you take out the array and can you load it from a file? Like <<<EOD file.txt EOD; etc

Comment: @user2733875 How about trying a little solving _your_ problem _yourself_? Gotta go - good luck!

Comment: Loading from a file: `$options = file_get_contents('file.txt');`. - Have you ever considered the http://php.net/manual ? That's where I learned all this. You can, too.